# Accessing data in a loop of text field with ColdFusion

Tags: variables, loops, coldfusion

I am fairly new to ColdFusion, and don't quite understand how variable access works. I've created a table that generates a number of text fields named condesc#i#, where i is the current index in a cfloop.

I then have a second loop, that attempts to access the contents of each field that has been created. I have attempted to make access using #condesc#i##, but with no success.

How should I go about getting the information from these fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference dynamic variable names by using bracket notation and string concatenation:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#count#" index="i">
    #form['condesc' & i]#  <br />
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 5):

All variables are structures so you can access them like this:

```
form[ "condesc" & i ]
```

And dynamically build the keys.